# Getting 404 requested resource not available in spring restful web services

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I'm using spring 3.2.3.RELEASE version and tomcat 7. I wanted to build a sample REST API using spring framework. My web.xml looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/sample-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sample-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myProjects</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My sample-servlet.xml looks something like this:

```
<beans>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myprojects.sampleproject" />
</beans>
```

Basically I do not want any JSP files since I just want to return string(JSON string) from controller. My controller looks something like this:

```
package com.myprojects.sampleproject;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 *
 * @author author
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class sampleprojectController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHello() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

I was able to successfully create a war file and deploy it on tomcat. But when I hit localhost:8080/myProjects/user, I get 404. I'm using maven to build and deploy the package.

I've worked on JAX-RS before where in we could configure in netbeans to create a project to write web services and everything came in handy that time. But here I'm actually trying to convert a maven based project to a web application running on tomcat. To do that, I tried this sample and I'm unable to get that up and running. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your code is returning "hello world", by default spring mvc will try to find a page "hello world.jsp" as resolved by viewResolver if you want to return a String in the browser annotate your method with '@ResponseBody'. e.g. public @ResponseBody String getHello() {..

Comment: I added @ResponseBody. But still no luck

Comment: For some stringe reason it works flawlessly when run as a Spring Boot. But doesn't work, if exported as a WAR and manually copied to Tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want return body then use special annotation `@ResponseBody`. By default controller methods annotated with `@RequestMapping` must return view name.

```
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public String getHello() {
            return "hello world";
        }
```

EDIT:

Add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to your sample-servlet.xml.

Replace root context configuration file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/sample-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Move all spring configuration to root context `/WEB-INF/context.xml` and leave `/WEB-INF/sample-servlet.xml` empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       ">
</beans>
```

Comment: I got the issue now. When I was deploying the war file to tomcat7, I'm getting this error: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]. What exactly should be there in applicationContext.xml. I was assuming the sample-servlet.xml and web xml will suffice. Could you please explain what needs to be added in this xml?

Comment: I fixed this issue by adding applicationContext.xml. When deploying to tomcat I even got: Mapped "{[/user],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.myprojects.sampleproject.sampleprojectController.getHello(). But when I hit localhost:8080/myProjects/user, I get resource not available. In web.xml, url-pattern is /myProjects and in controller, the RequestMapping is /user. Hence Im assuming /myProjects/user is the url. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @coder: maybe replace servlet mapping /myProjects to /myProjects/*

Comment: Finally got the issue. Netbeans had set some default context path: /<myprojectname>. So my url is /<myProjectname>/myProjects/user. I guess this is set in META-INF/context.xml.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are missing the context path of your project. If you are using eclipse you can find the context path in the project properties --> Web Project settings.

Also, make sure there no errors on your console.

Comment: I use netbeans and in project properties I dont see web project settings. Actually I had written a stand alone maven based application  initially. Now I'm trying to add a wrapper to this to create REST web services. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: logs will be available on TOMCAT_HOME/logs right? I dont see any logging happening when I hit the page. Is there any other location where I can check the logs?

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you need to put the RequestMapping for your method with a /. Something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getHello() {
    return "hello world";
}
```